# React js swiping card showing alternate cards instead of every card

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to use `react-swipe-card` for the functionality of swiping cards. I also have my own functionality of adding the users being liked or disliked into appropriate objects `liked` and `disliked`. However, instead of showing every card, it shows the alternate cards. Can someone help?

```
const users = {
  '0ggijDr0VpfRZO23f4R6QCSnlJw2': {
    firstName: 'Joe'
  },
  '6VNYWdIKkhfqnJpYpvk2xWX9pqx2': {
    firstName: 'Grace'
  },
  AxVNYWdIKkhfqnJpYpvk2xWX9pq1: {
    firstName: 'John'
  }
}
```

In this users object, userId is a key.

```
const Wrapper = ({ data, onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight }) => {
  return (
    <Cards onEnd={console.log("action('end')")} className='master-root'>
      {Object.keys(data).map(item => (
        <Card
          key={data[item]}
          onSwipeLeft={() => onSwipeLeft()}
          onSwipeRight={() => onSwipeRight()}
        >
         <h2>{data[item].firstName}</h2>
       </Card>
      ))}
    </Cards>
  )
}

export default class MyCards extends Component {
  state = {
    data: users,
    liked: {},
    disliked: {}
  }

  onSwipeLeft = () => {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.state.data)

    let dislikedId = Object.keys(this.state.data).shift()

    let dislikedTemp = Object.assign({},{ [dislikedId]: this.state.data[dislikedId] })

    delete newData[dislikedId]

    const newDisliked = Object.assign({}, this.state.disliked, dislikedTemp)

    this.setState({ data: newData, disliked: newDisliked })
  }

  onSwipeRight = () => {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.state.data)

    let likedId = Object.keys(this.state.data).shift()

    let likedTemp = Object.assign({}, { [likedId]: this.state.data[likedId] })

    delete newData[likedId]

    const newLiked = Object.assign({}, this.state.liked, likedTemp)

    this.setState({ data: newData, liked: newLiked })
  }

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper
        onSwipeLeft={this.onSwipeLeft}
        onSwipeRight={this.onSwipeRight}
        data={this.state.data}
      />
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Source reference: https://github.com/alexandre-garrec/react-swipe-card

I am unable to figure out why it doesn't show up every card. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you add code sandbox for the same?

Comment: Hi @Pooja Shah, Check it over here https://react-5qr7ev.stackblitz.io. I think your code is fine, but ``react-swipe-card`` is not re-rendering newly set data properly.

Comment: Hi Sandip, the codesandbox is similar to this https://codesandbox.io/embed/k0zkorz3j7?codemirror=1. I saw the link you shared. It’s the same problem that I am also facing. Do you know what is the solution to it?